# Exploring Diffrences and Agreement with Wilcoxon and Kendall - both tests show significant findings

Tags: statistical-significance, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I calculated a Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test to investigate differences between a pair of dependend variables. Also I conducted a Kendall's tau-b on the same variables. Surprisingly both tests get significant.

I wonder how this is possible because Wilcoxon tries to identify group diffrences and Kendall's correlation is about to quantify concordance.

Is there an explenation of this phenomenon?

Comment: This result may or may not be surprising. It is hard to say. Can you provide more detail about your situation, your data & your goals?

Comment: Think about this example.  $x$ is distributed uniformly over $(0,1)$, and $y = 1 + x$.  Wilcoxon will clearly be significant, for any reasonable sample size, as $\min y > \max x$, and Kendall will clearly be significant, since the two variables are indeed perfectly correlated.

Comment: Thanks Greg Snow and @jbowman. This is absolutly reasonable. I provide a feedback after checking my data.

Comment: Imagine a plot of y vs x. Signed rank test considers a question like "are the points close to the y-x line?" while the Kendall says "when one increases, does the other tend to do the same?". They're pretty much completely unrelated questions. For example you could multiply x by 10 and add 12, and the Kendall correlation would be exactly the same as before but the signed rank test would be completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this simple example:

Group A is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Group B is 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Now the groups are clearly different in mean/median/position.  Each pair has a difference of 5.  But there is also correlation in that given a value in one of the groups you can perfectly compute/predict the corresponding value in the other group.  With this data we would expect both tests to show very significant.  I expect that your data is similar (but with more variability).

Comment: Sorry, Greg!  I added my comment to the OP through the "review" process, and consequently didn't see your answer (+1).  I'll be more careful in the future.